# Adicionando Admob no Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou tentando colocar monetização no meu app ionic. Pesquisando, encontrei alguns exemplos mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar. O banner simplesmente não aparece.

Segui esse [exemplo](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/adding-admob-to-ionic-framework-application-step-by-step/), que eh bem simples por sinal, mas não consigo fazer funcionar, o banner não aparece.

Como colocar admob em aplicativos ionic ?

Comment: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/ quem sabe pode ajudar um pouco

Comment: @Otto funcionou perfeito. Uma duvida que tenho eh com relacao aos banners, para melhor monetizar eu ja ouvi falar que a cada tela do aplicativo tenho que forçar a troca de banner, pois assim o $$ eh melhor. Isso eh verdade ? se for como faço para trocar os banners a cada tela ? obrigado

Comment: Fernando, posta aqui depois seu feedback a respeito, tô interessado nisso.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva fala mestre adicionei como resposta para ajudar a galera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue link com exemplo completo de integração:
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

Exemplo de integração:

```
var admobApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
                var admob_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ANDROID_PUBLISHER_KEY" : "IOS_PUBLISHER_KEY";
                var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
                admob.createBannerView( 
                    {
                        'publisherId': admob_key,
                        'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                        'bannerAtTop': false
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        admob.requestAd(
                            { 'isTesting': false }, 
                            function() {
                                admob.showAd(true);
                            }, 
                            function() { console.log('failed to request ad'); }
                        );
                    }, 
                    function() { console.log('failed to create banner view'); }
                );
            }
        });
    });
```